# How to make what the menu will automatically closes?

Tags: javascript, ios, mootools

Need to do so that would be the menu closes when you click to another area of ​​the screen, please help, i'm use mootools functions

```
toggleMenu: function() {
    if (menuOpened) {
        $('home-menu').setStyle('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(-50px)');
        menuOpened = false;
    }
    else {
        $('home-menu').setStyle('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(0px)');
        menuOpened = true;
    }
},
```

Comment: Could you add HTML for the menu so its more clear what you have.

Comment: @Sergio, i haven't html for menu, I'm created menu uses moo tools functions and css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449501/mootools-open-close-popup-menu-and-outer-click-event see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to close the menu if there is a click outside the menu.

Suggestion (assuming the menu is open):

```
window.addEvent('click', function (e) {
    // this line under will give true if the click is outside the menu
    if (e.target.id != 'home-menu' && !e.target.getParent('#home-menu')) myFunctionSpace.toggleMenu();  
});
```

#### Example: http://jsbin.com/dicuquwe/1/